# switch statement with an default clause at the beginning java

Tags: java, switch-statement, default

The following code prints out  `1,2,3` , if i change `int i = 3;` it will print out `3`. I was wondering the reason behind this. I used debugger and it seems if `i = 3` it goes to case 3 and print out 3 then program terminated.I believe when `i=5`, it goes to `default` , does this mean `case 1,case 2 and case 3` all belong to the `default` clause?

```
int i = 5;
switch(i){
default:
case 1:
    System.out.println(1);
case 2:
    System.out.println(2);
case 3:
    System.out.println(3);

}
```

Edit:
This question was from a test and it asks for the output for this code. So I am trying to figure out why the output is `1,2,3`, i understand `break;` is needed but that is not what i wanted for the answer.

Comment: You need `break;` statements at the end of each case, or else execution will `/* fall through */` to the case below it.

Comment: @rgettman thanks for the reminder but this was not my question, i left 'break;' out on purpose for this question.

Comment: Actually, it does.  The absence of `break` statements completely explains your output, and why some cases seem to "belong" to others.

Comment: Then please re-insert them.  The `break`s are essential here.

Comment: "belong to the default clause" isn't really a thing that makes sense.  Things don't belong to clauses; there are just points where the `switch` can go to, and the `default` case is at the beginning.

Comment: `default:` and `case ... :`  are just jump labels whereto the switch jumps. And then the statemens are executed from there. Without a `break;` case 2 would print 2 and 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `i == 5` doesn't match any of your `case`s, so control goes to `default` clause.
- `default` clause is empty, with no `break` statement, and it immediately [*falls through*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough) to the `case` below — `case 1` in your code.
- `case 1` prints `"1"` and, as it also doesn't have a `break` statement, falls through to `case 2`, and so on.

---

`case`s `1`, `2`, `3` *do not belong* to `default` — what matters is their order.

If you would reorder your switch `statement` and would write `default` clause as the last one, it would print nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have break at any case or default it will fall through until it find break or end of case block. So in you case since you don't have break in default it fall through all the way to the end. Without break your program will print 1,2,3 for i>3.

Comment: yes @5gon12eder you are right I have removed the always.